# doctrine 1.2 generate-migrations-diff generates only foreign keys migration

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2

in schema.yml i add two tables

```
Block:
  columns:
    name:
      type: string(255)
      notblank: true

BlockItem:
  columns:
    block_id:
      type: integer
      notnull: true
    name:
      type: string(255)
      notblank: true
  relations:
    Block:
      class: Block
      foreignAlias: BlockItems
      onDelete: CASCADE
```

then i run `symfony doctrine:generate-migrations-diff`

and this task generates only one migration file

with `createForeignKey` but do not generate file with `createTable`

could someone help?

> FOUND BAD SOLUTION

if i delete all other migration files

all works fine

but it's an ugly solution
because after this i need to restore deleted migrations

and then rename new files and classes

Comment: The `doctrine:generate-migration-diff` task looks at the differences between current model files and the schema.yml - you must have already generated the model files for that table ?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9856243/is-it-possible-to-run-the-task-symfony-doctrine-build-all-on-only-one-table/9856555#9856555)... maybe helps

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely that your migration version file order is messed up, i.e. one or more files missing. Double check if the number of files matches migration version in db and if every file name is what is supposed to be, no gaps. nnnnnn_version_1.php following by nnnnn_version_2.php folowing by ...3.php and so on.